# fetch excel cell display value using Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, excel-formula, apache-poi

Below shows the highlighted cell which display as `-` (hyphen) but actually has `0` value inside it.

[image]

It's a formula cell with following custom formatting.

[image]

It's a formula cell but when the result is `0`, it displays as `-`.

My requirement is to fetch `-` instead of `0`.

```
cell2Update = sheet.getRow(4).getCell(3);
cell2Update.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC);
System.out.println(cell2Update.getStringCellValue());//Exception 
System.out.println(cell2Update.getNumericCellValue());//Display as 0
```

Please help me with this doubt. I want to display the value which is displayed in Spreadsheet (`-`).

Answer (score 3):

Do using a `DataFormatter` as shown in [Getting the cell contents](https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#CellContents). And because the value might be result of a formula. Do using using a [DataFormatter](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/DataFormatter.html) together with a [FormulaEvaluator](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/FormulaEvaluator.html):

```
...
DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter(); 
FormulaEvaluator evaluator = workbook.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator(); 
...
cell2Update = sheet.getRow(4).getCell(3);
...
String value = formatter.formatCellValue(cell2Update, evaluator);
System.out.println(value);
...
```

From Apache POI version 5.2.0 on the `DataFormatter` can set to use cached values for formula cells. Thus cell values resulting from formulas can be got without evaluating all formulas again.

```
...
DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter(); 
//from 5.2.0 on the DataFormatter can set to use cached values for formula cells, 
//thus no FormulaEvaluator needed
dataFormatter.setUseCachedValuesForFormulaCells(true);
...
cell2Update = sheet.getRow(4).getCell(3);
...
String value = formatter.formatCellValue(cell2Update,);
System.out.println(value);
...
```